# Function with Table_name as input and returns a number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have a function that takes table_name as input and returns a number. 
The function gets compiled properly but for some reason when I try test the function it throws error - missing keyword.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION (name_table IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER

        IS         

          rday NUMBER;                
  BEGIN 

  execute immediate 
  'select day_i into rday
                FROM ' || name_table || '
                WHERE day_i = 1 and rownum = 1';

   return rday;

  END TEST_FUNCTION;
```

This is how I am testing it `Select TEST_FUNCTION ('FDR_REP') from dual;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for execute immediate is different for an into clause
try

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION (name_table IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER

        IS         

          rday NUMBER;                
  BEGIN 
   execute immediate  'select day_i 
                FROM ' || name_table || '
                WHERE day_i = 1 and rownum = 1' into rday;


   return rday;

  END TEST_FUNCTION;
```